# How to secure profile links from unregistered users?

Tags: authentication

I want to ask if I had given the link of a logged in user and then I go to that link without logging in, then how can I secure data. I mean it can be possible that his private messages can be seen by unregistered user. So I am making a website and I want to secure data from unregistered users. Can anybody help?Also can anyone tell me how can I redirect the link to Login page when the unregistered user try to open the above link?

Comment: Please add more tags, including the language. What have you tried? This is a standard feature for most modern languages and frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

generally you can use `$_SESSION` variable to identify whether the user has been logged in or not. 
Now the profile page will have many elements like his private messages, links, his email address, edit profile link etc. Which you want to protect from unauthorized user. So First of all check whether the user is logged in or not by:

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) { // $_SESSION['loggedIn'] is the variable I set to //TRUE when user filled the registration/login form. Otherwise it is set to FALSE.
  echo 'user is logged in';
  //rest of code goes here
}
```

**METHOD 1 -**

Now check whether the user is website user or not.Check by using MySql query. Well, you can make a function for it.

function userisregistered(){
//code to check sql database for current logged in user
//returns TURE if user is registered, FALSE otherwise
}

One thing you said that you wanted the user to get redirected to another page if he is unregistered. You can do that so by-

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){ //USER IS UNAUTHENTICATED --NO ACCESS
     header('Location: URL_of_page_you_want_user_to_redirect');
}
```

**METHOD 2 -**

Now I assume here that if the user is authenticated to the website, he can access all the profile features of the userX, otherwise not. So for that part, I could come up with the advantage of ajax, which would fetch the details and creates the DOM elements. code goes like this-

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) and userisregistered()){ //USER IS AUTHENTICATED --ALL FEATURES
     echo '<ul>\n<li>item1</li>\n<li>item2</li>\n<li>item3</li></ul>';

}
else if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){  //USER IS AUTHENTICATED  --LIMITED FEATURES
     echo '<ul>\n<li>item1</li>\n<li>item2</li>\n</ul>';
}
else   //NO ACCESS
           header('Location: URL_of_page_you_want_user_to_redirect');
```